# Managing Cassandra data storage size and backups under Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, database-backups

I would like to run a Cassandra cluster under Kubernetes on Google Container Engine using the examples given here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/storage/cassandra

The file describes 3 ways to setup the cluster - PetSet(StatefulSet), Replication Controller and DaemonSet. Each one of them has its pros and cons.

While trying to choose the best setup for me, I noticed that I cannot figure out what to do with the storage and backups.

1. How can I set or scale the storage size (increase/decrease node/cluster **data storage** size without data loss) ?
2. How do I manage backups and restores?

Comment: One option to attach storage to your Node/Cluster is to map [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) as a network disk using [FUSE adapter](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse). If you configure [Replication controller](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/replication-controller/) for your Kubernetes cluster it will ensure that a specified number of pods are running at any one time.

Comment: @Faizan Not really relevant for my questions... I have no control over with pods runs in an instance so I can easily make a mess when pods are restarted or scaled and multiple pods run on the same instance. I'm pretty sure the storage should be attached to a pod and not a node. never the less, it's not helping me with scaling storage nor managing backups.

Comment: @Idan have you found solution for this since you've asked this question? I'm facing the same case right now.

Comment: @sev3ryn nope :\ and stopped actively looking for one...

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out Flocker and Flockerhub from ClusterHQ. I've been playing around with their products in order to prove with a POC that containerized sharded db's can be done in an easy and manageable way. Make sure to check them out:
https://clusterhq.com/

They are handling data the same way as docker images are being handled. So you will be able to push and pull data volumes into a hub/repository.

Comment: Looks like a good product. But it's a volume driver that ensures that your pod will run with its own volume data and not an empty one after restarting. The cons are 1) Not really sure how will it work with replication controllers (will continue reading) 2) you need to pre-create all volumes (no auto scale) 3) no resizing of existing volumes.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there is no way to do this in kubernetes. Kubernetes does very little in terms of storage management.

If you have the flexibility of choosing other solutions, [check this out](https://robinsystems.com/product-and-solutions/robin-for-databases/).

They provide a container-based solution that combines compute, network, storage, so you have full control over all resources required by cassandra, and perform snapshot/restore, scale out, scale up/down, etc.